# PHP - String not displayed correctly despite UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, encoding, utf-8

I've got some data stored in a UTF-8 ecoded table in mysql. When i view the data in phpmyadmin, it is displayed correctly, like this

★ StatTrak™ M9 Bayonet | Blue Steel (Minimal Wear)

However, when I output this data to a UTF-8 encoded document via the print command, it is not displayed correctly. It looks like this:

? StatTrak� Flip Knife | Fade (Factory New)

I've been searching the internet for a while now. What I've done so far is I've set 'default_charset' in php to UTF-8 and configured nginx to use the same encoding. I've checked the page info in Firefox and it says it's UTF-8-Encoded, so that seems to work. What I don't understand is why it's still not displaying the characters correctly.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that needs to be done:

1.Setting mysql encoding in queries to UTF-8 (i don't mean collision).
 2.Set characeter encoding in output of your HTML code.

For mysql you need to execute these queries right after opening connection to database:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8");
mysqli_query($con,"SET CHARACTER_SET utf8");
```

And to show your data in html output in UTF-8 encoding use this meta tag in your head section:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
<body>
    <?php print("your code here..."); ?>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, you were a little faster than me, I was already typing my answer when you replied. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Awesome! I was tearing my hair out over this!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. You need to tell MySQL that you want to keep the UTF-8 Encoding when you execute your query by executing the following query:

SET NAMES 'utf8'

This will keep the UTF-8 encoding and everything will be displayed correctly.